# how to find if replication role of Azure SQL database

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am trying to find the replication role of Azure SQL DB (Primary or Secondary).

I used :  `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase`  command but could not find the replication information.

Is there a different powershell command to find replication role ?

Answer (score 3):

> The [Get-AzureRMSqlDatabaseReplicationLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/get-azurermsqldatabasereplicationlink?view=azurermps-4.3.1) cmdlet replaces the
> Get-AzureSqlDatabaseCopy cmdlet.
>
> It gets all geo-replication links
> between the specified Azure SQL Database and a resource group or
> AzureSQL Server.

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseReplicationLink -DatabaseName <databaseName> -PartnerResourceGroupName <partnerResourceGroupName> -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -ServerName <databaseServerName> | Select Role
```

Below is the result of the Azure PowerShell cmdlet above which get the replication role of the geo-replicated Azure SQL Databases.

[image]

Note:

The **partnerResourceGroupName** and **resourceGroupName** can be the same if the geo-replicated databases and server are in the same resource group as the primary.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseReplicationLink` cmdlet. Refer to this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-setup-geodr-and-failover-database-powershell

```
$database = New-AzureRmSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName $primaryresourcegroupname `
    -ServerName $primaryservername `
    -DatabaseName $databasename -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S0"

# Establish Active Geo-Replication
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $databasename -ResourceGroupName $primaryresourcegroupname -ServerName $primaryservername
$database | New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseSecondary -PartnerResourceGroupName $secondaryresourcegroupname -PartnerServerName $secondaryservername -AllowConnections "All"

# Initiate a planned failover
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $databasename -ResourceGroupName $secondaryresourcegroupname -ServerName $secondaryservername
$database | Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseSecondary -PartnerResourceGroupName $primaryresourcegroupname -Failover

# Monitor Geo-Replication config and health after failover
$database = Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $databasename -ResourceGroupName $secondaryresourcegroupname -ServerName $secondaryservername
$database | Get-AzureRmSqlDatabaseReplicationLink -PartnerResourceGroupName $primaryresourcegroupname -PartnerServerName $primaryservername
```